# SSRS Subreport call parent report's code

Tags: reporting-services, report

Is there a way for a subreport in SSRS to call its parent report's code? I know that "Code.FunctionName()" calls code that is in the subreport's code section, but can I use something like "Parent.Code.FunctionName()" to access a parent's code?

Answer (score 1):

I think that idea is flawed, as the report wouldn't be able to be run unless in a subreport of another report.. And I don't think SSRS supports it.

The way to share code between reports is to use an external .dll

It's quite easy to set up and you can write the code in C# as well as VB.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769

Comment: Thanks Sam...I was thinking that was probably the case, but was hoping there might be a workaround.